# Sharing redisson client connection pool between several redisson client bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis, redisson, connection-pool

I had different objects, saved in `redis`. This objects has different structures.
I need to use custom codec to serialize and deserialize it.
I had three beans.

```java
@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public RedissonClient redissonClientA() {
    Config config = getConfig();
    config.setCodec(new ObjectABaseCodec(objectMapper));
    return Redisson.create(config);
}

@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public RedissonClient redissonClientB() {
    Config config = getConfig();
    config.setCodec(new ObjectBBaseCodec(objectMapper));
    return Redisson.create(config);
}

@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")
public RedissonClient redissonClientC() {
    Config config = getConfig();
    config.setCodec(new ObjectCBaseCodec(objectMapper));
    return Redisson.create(config);
}
```

And I had three redisson client with three objects with connections to redis.
And in nearest future we planned add new objects. And I don't want increase count of connections to redis.

First Idea: I want, but I don't wont how share redisson connection pool between several redisson clients.

Second Idea:use common codec and inside common codec decide which object I have and after that use current codec implementation.

Maybe you know how i can realize first idea?